# What does this SQL-query mean?

Tags: sql, database

I am finding hard time underestanding this query. I know this gives me all supplier names for suppliers who supply all parts that exist to a project. but only because I found the answers online!

```
    select sname 
    from s 
    where not exists (select * 
                      from p 
                      where not exists (select * 
                                        from spj spjx 
                                        where s.sno = spjx.sno and
                                              p.pno = spjx.pno
                                       )
                     );
```

Comment: It is a classic [relational division approach](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). Find all Suppliers for which there is no Part that they do not supply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to reformat it:

```
select sname from s                          -- show all supplier names
where not exists                             -- that there is not 
      (select * from p                       -- a part
       where not exists                      -- that is not
             (select * from spj spjx         -- supplied
              where s.sno = spjx.sno         -- by them
                and p.pno = spjx.pno));
```

Basically: select all sname from s, where no p exists where no spj such that spj matches s and p. Think of each layer as a filter.

And the result looks like a relational division, as point out by Martin in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it like sets filtering sets. There are three sets here:

```
select * from spj spjx
where s.sno = spjx.sno and
    p.pno = spjx.pno

select * from p
where not exists ({previous set})

select sname from s
where not exists ({previous set})
```

So, everywhere you see `{previous set}`, the outer set is being filtered by the result of that set.

Further, for completeness, when you see this:

```
from spj spjx
```

that's equivalent to:

```
from spj AS spjx
```

thus making `spjx` the `alias` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying
     "*show all suppliers who supply **every** part*",
it says
     "*Show all suppliers for whom no part is not supplied by them*"